# multiple targets in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am handling a project for education university ,where there are **5 seperate universities** **each university having there own app** but in each application **images ,json** differs and the  **source code** remains same .
*i want to create 5seperate apks with different package name using only one source code and if any change done in source code should update in all apks.*

please give me structure of project ,graddle.build tool setting and if i need to make library how and where it will be, or please upload a sample to do above type in detail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following Android Developers guide [Configuring Gradle Builds](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants) I was able to create application sharing same code with different resources.

Firstly, after creating new project in Android Studio (Gradle: Android Module), I added to build.gradle file (residing in your module directory, like 'Project/app/build.gradle') 'blue' and 'red' flavors:

```
android {
// ...
    productFlavors {
        blue {
            applicationId 'com.example.app.blue'
            versionName '1.0-blue'
        }
        red {
            applicationId 'com.example.app.red'
            versionName '1.0-red'
        }
    }
}
```

IDE requested to sync project files with Gradle, so I did it. Then I added resource file colors.xml to 'red' flavor by right-clicking directory 'app' in project root in *Project* panel (New -> Android resource file, selected 'red' as my *Source Set*).

Next I modified new file to contain definition of color resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="primary">#ff0000</color>
</resources>
```

I did the same for my 'blue' flavor (but with different color value).

I changed background color of activity layout created automatically while creating new project to see if it'll work.

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...
    android:background="@color/primary" />
```

Switching Build Variant in *Build Variants* panel (opened by lower-left button names such) resulted in different background colors in my activity.

I assume you keep your images, json and other files in Android resurces directories, so the way you should keep different files in different flavors is similiar to what I've achieved.

See [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants) site to better understand product flavors and Build Variants.

Comment: hi, i get graddle build error,   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processYoga_frenchDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.unders.app.y_v1f'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Answer (score 0):

[image: project structure for generating multiple apks using single source set]

- main is the parent directory having my source code ,res,assets.
- flavour1,flavour2,flavour3 are my child directory where they have different images,json and are placed as shown under flavour1 ,similarly done with flavour2,flavour3.
- using build variant select the flavour to be run and respective apk is generated.
- whatever resources which are placed inside the flavour are overiding the resources inside the main ,thus images and localjson of flavour1 are getting populated.